# Как сделать операцию умножения коммутативной?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

```
class Money {
    ///Поля
    unsigned long long rubles; 
    unsigned char penny; 
...
}
...
Money Money::DoubleToMoney(double num) {
    double first = 0.0,
        second = modf(num, &first); //дробная часть числа = modf(число, целая часть числа)
    //вынимаем целую часть из дробного и присваиваем к рублям
    this->rubles = unsigned long long(first);
    //первые 2 значения из дробного числа присваиваем копейкам
    second *= 100;
    first = modf(second, &second);
    this->penny = unsigned char(second);
    return *this;
}
...
double Money::MoneyToDouble() const { return (rubles * 100 + penny) / 100.0; }
...
Money operator*(const Money & ob, const double & amount) { return Money{}.DoubleToMoney(ob.MoneyToDouble() * amount);}
Money operator*(const double & amount, const Money & ob) { return Money{}.DoubleToMoney(ob.MoneyToDouble() * amount);}
Money operator/(const Money & ob, const double & amount) { return Money{}.DoubleToMoney(ob.MoneyToDouble() / amount);}
```

Ответ: вынести операторы из класса

Comment: Можно. Вынесите оператор из класса.

Comment: Вынес операторы из класса, посмотрел несколько сайтов и реализовал преобразование из MoneyToDouble и теперь все работает красивенько :) Спасибо

Comment: Ну, я бы деньги считал в копейках. По-моему, удобнее, а главное, точнее. Правда, инфляция... `long long` может не хватить :) Последнее шутка, первое — нет!

Comment: Операция деления и не должна быть коммутативной. Как вы себе представляете `1/(1[руб]) == 1[руб]` ?

Comment: Точно! Совсем не заметил. Про подсчет денег в копейках мне тоже приходила мысля, но заказчик (препод) хочет именно так :P

Comment: А что если сделать implicit конструктор с параметром типа double?

Comment: Хороший совет, обговорю с преподом, а потом может и сделаю так

Comment: @VoidTimesWithNull, Я не уверен, что это заработает, напишите потом.